# Linux Shell Script - Send command over TCP to Sharp Aquos

Tags: shell, tcp

I'm writing a shell script that needs to send an 8 character string terminated with a x0d to a Sharp Aquos TV. An example is `'POWR1   \x0d'` (POWR1 followed by three spaces and LF)

The documentation is poor. it says protocol TCP/IP (nothing about UDP or TCP) and service: nothing: do not select telnet or SSH.

In the past, for similar projects I've been able to use socat and something like:

```
echo -e -n 'POWR1   \x0d' | socat - tcp4:192.168.1.88:10002
```

However, all I get is `"socat[3875] E connect(3, AF=2 192.168.1.88:10002, 16): Connection refused"`

Anyone got any ideas

Comment: I usually use netcat (nc) the same way - but if the remote refuses the connection even before you send anything, it doesn't really matter what you use. You have to make the remote server to accept your connections first.

Comment: Just for the record `0x0d` (13) is CR. LF is `0x0a` (10)

Answer (score 0):

Displays with network control features often ship with the feature disabled. Look in the manual to see if there is a way to enable it.

I would have done the manual diving for you, but you don't give a model number.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe info from [this post](http://forum.micasaverde.com/index.php?topic=10365.0) will help.

Enable IP on TV set

> ... I allowed the Sharp to controlled using the Network settings tab on the TV and also set up a static IP. All internet stuff on the TV works fine ...

Answer (score 0):

I have working solution for you. You need to:

Open Menu -> Settings -> View Settings -> Network Settings -> IP control Settings -> ChangeSet your tv name, username, password, port

After that you can send your commands so:

```
echo -e -n 'user\x0dpassword\x0dIAVD4   \x0d' | \
        socat - tcp4:192.168.100.113:10002
```

**NOTE:** for the above: (user/pass/ip/port insert with your values)